# Installing Magento and Drupal in the same directory... htaccess magic maybe?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, magento

We are looking to run one website using two CMS systems, so for all the content related stuff it would be drupal, and then for all the ecommerce related stuff, we are looking to use Magento.

Do you think this is possible? What are the general thoughts on this as an idea?

Usually we would have the ecommerce on a subfolder, like /store/productname... however, the client has specifically asked that we don't have it on a subfolder, hence asking for opinions on here.

Edit: For the sake of anyone thinking this is not programming related, I am wondering if there is something that you could achieve with the .htaccess file (rewrites etc).

Comment: why has this been flagged as Off Topic? I am asking about .htaccess/rewrite possibilities...

Comment: It's been flagged for migration to [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) where it might be more appropriate

Comment: There's lots of programatic solutions to this problem.

Comment: @AlanStorm: Do you know of any off the top of your head? I've really been struggling to come up with a satisfactory solution to this

Comment: @Clive: If I was doing it I'd create a custom router that bootstrapped drupal inside Magento. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch

Comment: @AlanStorm: Nice solution, I hadn't thought about that :)

Comment: @Clive I've been meaning to try something like that with multiple systems, but I've never found the time.

Comment: @AlanStorm: Looks like someone's made a start from the Drupal point of view: http://drupal.org/project/drupento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is really possible, both Drupal and Magento rewrite all incoming requests for non-existing files to `index.php` in the root.

I guess you could change one of the CMSs root files to `index2.php` and try to route requests for that CMS to the correct index file. However this means you will need to maintain a list of all paths that can be accessed by that particular CMS in the `.htaccess` file itself, which would be a real pain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I agree with what you're saying. Hopefully I can collect enough evidence to convince them that it's a crazy idea!

Comment: I think crazy is about right! It might be worth arguing that having the products in a separate folder is actually better for the site's navigational structure, which in turn is much better for SEO. You could suggest the sub-folder be called (e.g.) `/exhaust-pipes/` (if the site happens to sell exhaust pipes) and that will bolster SEO performance quite considerably as opposed to having the product name in the route. In my experience people tend to have less of a problem with your ideas when you mention SEO benefits :)